# Eclipse keyboard shortcut to indent source code to the left?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I've looked in the keyboard shortcuts list in Eclipse but can't find keyboard shortcut to indent source code to the left. Surely there is one?

Comment: Real answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18643358/6490459

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In my copy, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> does this, as long as I have a code selection, and am in a code window.

Comment: If you are using VIM bindings (vrapper), unfortunately the usual shift > combination does not work. However, tab and shift tab do both work IF you are in INSERT mode.

Comment: And the file should be opened as a JavaScript Editor File.
Like if i have it open with UX Studio the shortcut doesn't work... And vice versus I can't add breakpoints for debugging.

Answer (score 84):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (indentation). See at http://www.rossenstoyanchev.org/write/prog/eclipse/eclipse3.html
Search for Indentation.

Comment: I was working on an xml file and this just delets the text I have selected.

Comment: you might have pressed Ctrl+Alt+i so that it was get deleted.

Comment: Cmd + I for Mac users.

Answer (score 61):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> which will run your formatter on the file and fix indentations along the way also.

Comment: How is this not the #1 answer?

Comment: This works far better after customizing your `formatter` preferences. Unless your code-style matches eclipses ideals. Until you do that, it can be quite frustrating if done accidentally.

Comment: A good formatter if you dont have one: https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/source/browse/trunk/eclipse-java-google-style.xml. Then in Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

Answer (score 15):

I thought it was <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> will do the work

Comment: command + shift + F worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For `Left indent` <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

For `Right indent` simple <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

In any version of Eclipse IDE for source code indentation.

Select the source code and use the following keys

1. For default java indentation <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
2. For right indentation <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. For left indentation <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Obviously this is only for Pydev, but I've worked out that you can get the very useful functions "Shift Right" and "Shift Left" (mapped by default to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) to become useful by changing their keybindings to "Pydev Editor Scope" from "Pydev View"

Answer (score 3):

On Mac (on french keyboard its) <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: `cmd+shit+F` is the shortcut for "Format" it does more than indenting, to correct only indentation it's `cmd+i`, to answer this question which is "shortcut to indent source code to the **left**" it's `shift+tab`

Answer (score 1):

Tab to indent right by four characters

Answer (score 0):

i'd rather go to menu source em click on "Cleanup Document"

Answer (score 0):

for me the default is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>,

you can select the text you want, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to shift everything on the left,
selecting all and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> shifts everything to the right.

Comment: don't know who disliked this. this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac Users who using Eclipse Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>(Indent)  and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>(Format). But I had worst experience with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> which breaks the code in to several lines as follows

```
String A = MyClass.getA(x, y);
if (A != null) {
    A = Long.parseLong(0);
}
```

Where my original code is as follows

```
String A = MyClass.get(x, y);
if (A != null) {
    A = Long.parseLong(0);
}
```