# Problems with indentation in eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse, node.js

I am trying to indent my code with Ctrl+Shift+F but each of the word is coming on a seperate line.
Heres my code after indentation.

```
$("#addSectionInRole")
                            .click(
                                    function() {
                                        $(this).hide();
                                        $("#addSectionForm").show();
                                        getRoles()
                                                .done(
                                                        function(data) {
                                                            $
                                                                    .each(
                                                                            data,
                                                                            function(
                                                                                    i,
                                                                                    value) {
                                                                                $(
                                                                                        '#selectRoleFromSection')
                                                                                        .append(
                                                                                                $(
                                                                                                        '<option>')
                                                                                                        .text(
                                                                                                                value.name)
                                                                                                        .attr(
                                                                                                                'value',
                                                                                                                value.name));
                                                                            });
                                                        });
                                    });
```

This is jquery but I am getting same problem with node.js code also.

Comment: Refer this buddy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526771/eclipse-keyboard-shortcut-to-indent-source-code-to-the-left

Comment: @Santhucool Not helping me bro

Comment: Which version is this? Which editor is this?

Comment: @nitind Eclipse Luna

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Window/Preferences", type "Formatter" in the filter box and select the Javascript Formatter that will be shown in the left hand tree. There you can see various choices for JS formatters and you can also edit them. Either choose one that you like or edit your own. In the Formatter-Editor you can choose the conditions in which to add newlines, line sizes, indentation width etc.